# Text doesn't align in tabular

Tags: tables

Absolute latex noob here that is having some difficulties creating a cv. I started from a template I found online and adapting it bit by bit to fine tune it but I have come across an issue with alignment in the tabular which I already spend hours on trying to resolve it. Basically it looks like the year values in my table are overflowing into the margins. I have attached a picture here:
https://ibb.co/k1hS0v1

Then I have another question which I cannot really solve, why is there so much space between the about me and the Experience Section?

There is way more space here than between the Education and Skills.

My latex code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,final]{memoir}

% misc
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{bch}  % font
\pagestyle{empty}                   % no pagenumbering
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}         % no paragraph indentation


% required packages (add your own)
\usepackage{flowfram}                                       % column layout
\usepackage[top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}% margins
\usepackage{graphicx}                                       % figures
\usepackage{url}                                            % URLs
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}                    % color
\usepackage{multicol}                                       % columns env.
    \setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{paralist}                                       % compact lists
\usepackage{tikz}




\RequirePackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries\upshape\color{RoyalBlue}}{}{0em}{}[{\titlerule[2pt]}]

%@{\extracolsep{\fill}} breaks it...


% \newcommand{\cventry}[3]{
%  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ p{10cm} r}
%     {#1} & {#2} \\%
%     {#3} &\\%
%  \end{tabular*}  
%}

 \newcommand{\cventry}[3]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{1cm}} p{10cm} r}
      {\bfseries #1} & {#2} \\%
      {#3} &\\%
  \end{tabular*}

}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Create column layout
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define length commands
\setlength{\vcolumnsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\columnsep}{\vcolumnsep}

% frame setup (flowfram package)
% left frame
\newflowframe{0.2\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[left]
    \newlength{\LeftMainSep}
    \setlength{\LeftMainSep}{0.2\textwidth}
    \addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}

% small static frame for the vertical line
\newstaticframe{1.5pt}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}

% content of the static frame
\begin{staticcontents}{1}
\hfill
\tikz{%
    \draw[loosely dotted,color=RoyalBlue,line width=1.5pt,yshift=0]
    (0,0) -- (0,\textheight);}%
\hfill\mbox{}
\end{staticcontents}

% right frame
\addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1.5pt}
\addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}
\newflowframe{0.7\textwidth}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}[main01]



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define macros (for convience)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\Sep}{\vspace{1.5em}}
\newcommand{\SmallSep}{\vspace{0.5em}}

\newenvironment{AboutMe}
    {\ignorespaces\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} About me}}
    {\Sep\ignorespacesafterend}

\newcommand{\CVSection}[1]
    {\Large\textbf{#1}\par
    \SmallSep\normalsize\normalfont}

\newcommand{\CVItem}[1]
    {\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} #1}}







%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

% Left frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{photo}
    \vspace{-7cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{flushright}\small
    Name name \\
    \url{email@gmail.com}  \\
%   \url{www.howtotex.com} \\
    (xx) xxxxxx
\end{flushright}\normalsize
\framebreak


% Right frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\Huge\bfseries {\color{RoyalBlue} Name name} \\
\Large\bfseries  Current function \\

\normalsize\normalfont

% About me
\begin{AboutMe}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s\end{AboutMe}
% Experience
\section{Experience}
\cventry{master 1}{2017--2020}{school}
\vspace*{1.5mm}
\noindent
\cventry{master 1}{2017--2019}{school}
\vspace*{1.5mm}
\noindent
\\
\cventry{master 1}{2017--Present}{school}
\vspace*{1.5mm}
\noindent

% Education
\section{Education}
\cventry{master 1}{2017--2020}{school}
\vspace*{1.5mm}
\noindent
\cventry{master 1}{2017--2019}{school}
\vspace*{1.5mm}
\noindent
\\
\cventry{master 1}{2017--Present}{school}
\vspace*{1.5mm}
\noindent

% Skills
\CVSection{Skills}
\CVItem{Platforms}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item Lorem 
    \item Ipsum 
\end{compactitem}
\end{multicols}
\SmallSep

\CVItem{Computer software}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item Lorem 
    \item Ipsum 
    \item Dolor 
    \item Sit 
    \item Amet
    \item Consectetur 
    \item Adipiscing 
    \item Elit
    \item \ldots
\end{compactitem}
\end{multicols}
\Sep 


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% End document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Comment: The about the extra space in the 'about me' I was able to resolve, I removed the \sep from \newenvironment{AboutMe}
 {\ignorespaces\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} About me}}
 {\Sep\ignorespacesafterend}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I redefined `\cventry` with `tabularx{\linewidth}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,final]{memoir}

% misc
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{bch} % font
\pagestyle{empty} % no pagenumbering
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % no paragraph indentation

% required packages (add your own)
\usepackage{flowfram} % column layout
\usepackage[top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}% margins
\usepackage{graphicx} % figures
\usepackage{url} % URLs
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % color
\usepackage{multicol} % columns env.
    \setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{paralist} % compact lists
\usepackage{tikz}

\RequirePackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries\upshape\color{RoyalBlue}}{}{0em}{}[{\titlerule[2pt]}]

 \newcommand{\cventry}[3]{%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X@{\hspace{1cm}}r@{}}%@{\extracolsep{1cm}}
{\bfseries #1} & {#2} \\%
{#3} &\\%
\end{tabularx}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Create column layout
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define length commands
\setlength{\vcolumnsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\columnsep}{\vcolumnsep}

% frame setup (flowfram package)
% left frame
\newflowframe{0.2\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[left]
    \newlength{\LeftMainSep}
    \setlength{\LeftMainSep}{0.2\textwidth}
    \addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}

% small static frame for the vertical line
\newstaticframe{1.5pt}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}

% content of the static frame
\begin{staticcontents}{1}
\hfill
\tikz{%
    \draw[loosely dotted,color=RoyalBlue,line width=1.5pt,yshift=0]
    (0,0) -- (0,\textheight);}%
\hfill\mbox{}
\end{staticcontents}

% right frame
\addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1.5pt}
\addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}
\newflowframe{0.7\textwidth}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}[main01]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define macros (for convience)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\Sep}{\vspace{1.5em}}
\newcommand{\SmallSep}{\vspace{0.5em}}

\newenvironment{AboutMe}
    {\ignorespaces\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} About me}}
    {\Sep\ignorespacesafterend}

\newcommand{\CVSection}[1]
    {\Large\textbf{#1}\par
    \SmallSep\normalsize\normalfont}

\newcommand{\CVItem}[1]
    {\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} #1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

% Left frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{photo}
    \vspace{-7cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{flushright}\small
    Name name \\
    \url{email@gmail.com} \\
% \url{www.howtotex.com} \\
    (xx) xxxxxx
\end{flushright}\normalsize
\framebreak

% Right frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\Huge\bfseries {\color{RoyalBlue} Name name} \\
\Large\bfseries Current function \\

\normalsize\normalfont

% About me
\begin{AboutMe}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s\end{AboutMe}
% Experience
\section{Experience}
\cventry{master 1}{2017--2020}{school}
\vspace*{1.5mm}
\cventry{master 1}{2017--2019}{school}
\vspace*{1.5mm}
\cventry{master 1}{2017--Present}{school}
\vspace*{1.5mm}
\noindent

% Education
\section{Education}
\cventry{master 1}{2017--2020}{school}
\vspace*{1.5mm}
\cventry{master 1}{2017--2019}{school}
\vspace*{1.5mm}
\cventry{master 1}{2017--Present}{school}
\vspace*{1.5mm}
\noindent

% Skills
\CVSection{Skills}
\CVItem{Platforms}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
 \item Lorem
 \item Ipsum
\end{compactitem}
\end{multicols}
\SmallSep

\CVItem{Computer software}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
 \item Lorem
 \item Ipsum
 \item Dolor
 \item Sit
 \item Amet
 \item Consectetur
 \item Adipiscing
 \item Elit
 \item \ldots
\end{compactitem}
\end{multicols}
\Sep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% End document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your rework!

Answer (score 1):

I focus only on definition of yours `\cventry`. Try if the following redesign solve your problem:

```
\newcommand{\cventry}[3]{%
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{} p{10cm}  % <---
    >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-10cm-2\tabcolsep\relax} % <---
                             @{}}         % <---
\bfseries #1    & #2    \\
#3              &       \\
\end{tabular*}\par\vspace*{1.5mm}         % <---
}
```

That above solution will work,  in preamble you need to load package `array`. Its working I tested with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,final]{memoir}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}         % no paragraph indentation
                                    % consequently in the document are all 
                                    % \noindet commands superfluous
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\cventry}[3]{%
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{} p{10cm}  
    >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-10cm-2\tabcolsep\relax}
                             @{}}
\bfseries #1    & #2    \\
#3              &       \\
\end{tabular*}\par\vspace*{1.5mm}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\section{Experience}
\cventry{master 1}{2017--2020}{school}
\cventry{master 1}{2017--2019}{school}
\cventry{master 1}{2017--Present}{school}

\section{Education}
\cventry{master 1}{2017--2020}{school}
\cventry{master 1}{2017--2019}{school}
\cventry{master 1}{2017--Present}{school}
\end{document}


\vspace*{1.5mm}
\noindent
\cventry{master 1}{2017--2019}{school}

\vspace*{1.5mm}
\noindent
\cventry{master 1}{2017--Present}{school}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% End document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

which gives.

[image]

(red lines indicate pages layout)

Please test in your real document, if you will obtain the same result concerning `\cventry`.

Comment: Thank for your reply and the explanation! Really appreciated!

Comment: @user195516, you are welcome. Apparently you more prefer colorful solutions than technically advanced :-). Happy TeXing